# Agora's custom video source example code gives error

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

I'm trying to set up a custom video source for a video stream in Agora for Unity, following the instructions from Agora's developer center here (and particularly, the example code at the bottom):

https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/custom_video_unity?platform=Unity

**THIS CODE WORKS.**  I can successfully send a video stream and watch it on another device and it looks correct.

**However**, the Unity console is reporting an error on every single frame, saying:

> D3D11 unsupported ReadPixels destination texture format (14)

Unity's documentation for [Texture2D.ReadPixels](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.ReadPixels.html) says that it works on RGBA32, ARGB32 and RGB24 texture formats, but Agora's example is using a texture in BGRA32 format.

If I alter the example to set the texture to RGBA32 format instead, then the program still works, except the colors are wrong--red and blue are swapped (unsurprisingly).

I tried to adjust the expected texture on Agora's end by modifying this line of the example:

```
externalVideoFrame.format = ExternalVideoFrame.VIDEO_PIXEL_FORMAT.VIDEO_PIXEL_BGRA;
```

But...there is no corresponding define for VIDEO_PIXEL_RGBA.  The available options are VIDEO_PIXEL_UNKNOWN, VIDEO_PIXEL_I420, VIDEO_PIXEL_BGRA, VIDEO_PIXEL_NV12, VIDEO_PIXEL_I422

So....my app is functioning correctly, but I'm drowning in error messages of dubious significance, which seems like it's going to cause headaches for development and debugging down the road.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

For the inverted color issue, make sure you have the same encoding format on the receiver side. If you are using the SDK script VideoSurface.cs, change the line where it instantiates the Texture (about line 172), where it should be like:
`nativeTexture = new Texture2D((int)defWidth, (int)defHeight, TextureFormat.BGRA32, false);`

(It was RGBA32 in the stock SDK code).

Answer (score 0):

Update: This format issue has been resolved in version 3.0.1. If it hasn't been released in Asset Store, you may come grab the beta to try out.  Check with slack channel here: https://agoraiodev.slack.com/messages/unity-help-me